# Linked List not properly initialising

Tags: java, hashmap

So I have a assignment hich involves creating your own implementation of a HashMap. My code - below works by first calling a constructor which sets the size of the Array. It then calculates the Hash value of a word to be added to the list. It goes to that position in the Array and checks whether there is a value there already. If there isn't, it creates a new Node there and adds the data, with the pointer pointing to null. If there is a Cell already there, it creates a new Cell but the pointer points to the Cell that was previously there, thus creating a Linked List.

My count method, works by first finding the hash value of the requested word. It then searches the linked list present at the point and returns a value.

```
public class WordStoreImp implements WordStore{

public class Node<T>{
   public T data;
   public Node<T> next;
   public Node(){
   }

   public Node(T data, Node<T> next)
   {
      this.data = data;
      this.next = next;
   }
}

static Node[] array;

public WordStoreImp(int n){
    array = new Node[n];
}

public void add(String word){
    int position = hashFunction(word);
    if(position<0){
        position =  position *- 1;
    }
    if(array[position] == null){
        array[position] = new Node(word, null);
    }else{
        Node newHead = new Node(word, array[position]);
        array[position] = newHead;
    }
}



public int count(String word){
        int number = 0;
        int position = hashFunction(word);
        if(position<0){
            position = position *- 1;
        }
        for(; array[position] != null; array[position] = array[position].next){
            if(array[position].data == word){
                number++;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println(number);
        return number;
    }

public int hashFunction(String a){
    int sum = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i<a.length(); i++){
            char b = a.charAt(i);
            int value = (int) b;
            sum *= value;
     }
     sum = sum % array.length;
     if(sum<0){
         sum = sum*-1;
     }
     return sum;
 }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    WordStoreImp a = new WordStoreImp(100);
    a.addthings("abc", 100);
    a.count("abc");
    a.count("abc");
}
}
```

My issue is that my count method is not working and I can't figure out why - the first time it returns how many times a item is present fine, but it then dosent work - and returns 0. I cant figure out why - can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the head of your linked list when you call your `count` method.  You are doing this in your `for` loop line:

```
for(; array[position] != null; array[position] = array[position].next){
```

When this loop is done, you've effectively moved all your linked list items off your bucket by repeatedly updating `array[position]` until it's `null`.

Instead, use a local variable initialized to `array[position]`, and update *it* instead of `array[position]`, something like this:

```
for(Node<T> curr = array[position]; curr != null; curr = curr.next){
    if(curr.data == word){
        number++;
    }
}
```

You may also want to consider using the `.equals` method; the `==` operator will determine if they are the same object, and two `equals` objects may not necessarily be the same object.